# How to share zero copy dataframes between processes with PyArrow

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I'm trying to work out how to share data between processes with PyArrow (to hopefully at some stage share pandas DataFrames). I am at a rather experimental (read: Newbie) stage and am trying to figure out how to use PyArrow. I'm a bit stuck and need help.

Going through the documentation, I found an [example to create a buffer](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/memory.html#pyarrow-buffer)

```py
import time
import pyarrow as pa

data = b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

buf = pa.py_buffer(data)

print(buf)
# <pyarrow.Buffer address=0x7fa5be7d5850 size=26 is_cpu=True is_mutable=False>


while True:
   time.sleep(1)
```

While this process was running, I used the address and size, that the script printed, to (try to) access the buffer in another script:

```
import pyarrow as pa

buf = pa.foreign_buffer(0x7fa5be7d5850, size=26)
print(buf.to_pybytes())
```

and received... a segmentation fault - most likely because the script is trying to access memory from another process, which I may require different handling.
Is this not possible with PyArrow or is the just the way I am trying to do this? Do I need other libraries? I'd like to avoid serialisation (or writing to disk in general), if possible, but this may or may not be possible. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share buffers across processes, instead you should use memory mapped file.

To write:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
mmap = pa.create_memory_map("hello.txt", 20)
mmap.write(b"hello")
```

To read:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
mmap = pa.memory_map("hello.txt")
mmap.read(5)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. How is `foreign_buffer` supposed to work though?

Comment: `foreign_buffer` is expecting a valid pointer to data.  An address from a different process is not a valid pointer.  Each process has its own virtual address space.  A pointer in one process is meaningless in a different process.

Answer (score 0):

You serialise your Pandas DataFrame, and then copy data into the shared memory, then you read it inside another process.

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

buffer = pa.serialize_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}))
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=buffer.size)
shm.buf[:buffer.size] = buffer.to_pybytes()
print(shm.name)
```

This should produce something like `psm_12345678`, now the buffer is in memory, and you can read it inside another python process:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

shm_name = 'psm_12345678' 

existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(shm_name)
buffer_reader = pa.BufferReader(existing_shm.buf)
pa.ipc.deserialize_pandas(buffer_reader.read())
```

That would produce DataFrame you've originally "saved".

I was trying to pre-allocate shared memory and make PyArrow serialise DataFrame straight into it, but I couldn't. Also, even logically it's quite tricky since we'll need to know the size of serialised object in advance, and we simply don't. I'm not sure if this is practical to do it this way, though.

Comment: Data serialisation is not an option for me. The dataframes I'm trying to share are large in size (multiple GBs) and any serialisation would run too long and duplicate memory needed - hence the attempt to share memory. I'd also like to avoid (hard) disk access for similar reasons.

Comment: Yeah - I think I understand what you're saying. But "sharing memory" is impossible in principle on DataFrames, since DataFrames are not of "constant type". You can share memory of NP arrays - that is you can create them inside shared memory, since you know how much memory they will take. But in case of DataFrames, they can have objects inside, and those are just pointers, hence you need serialisation. So, consider using Numpy (if you know size you can share them WITHOUT serialisation).
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html
Or, consider using threading.

Comment: From what I understand, you can't make memory "shared" after the fact. So, either you pre-allocate memory as "shared" and then you can put something there - something you know the size of, like NP array of a known size an type. Or, you serialise an object and copy it into shared memory. Even logically - your DataFrame can theoretically point to any object, so, "sharing DataFrame" is like sharing ALL the memory, and that's basically "threading".

Comment: Sharing memory between processes is not as straight-forward as sharing variables between threads (which run in the same thread). Hence the question... Pandas dataframes are also not as easy to share as changing a pointer (if that was allowed across processes) as they are not contiguous blocks of memory (not even the backing arrays are as they are grouped by type by the block manager).